# How to add custom function to sequelize.js in Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

For example I have a Client model.
I want to add new function "sendEmail"

The function needs to work send email to one client, or to send email to many clients at once?

Where to define those functions?

Comment: Probably you are looking for: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/stable/docs/models/#expansion-of-models

Comment: No. This is to run a method only on one instance (row).

Comment: But classMethods are for global model.

Comment: I want Client.FindAll(...).sendEmail... || It is not documentated How I make the classMethods to work on the returned rows from the FindAll

Answer (score 91):

Version 4 of sequelize has changed this and the other solutions with `instanceMethods` and `classMethods` do not work anymore.  See [Upgrade to V4 / Breaking changes](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/4478d74a3e5dc8cd30837d8a193754867d06ccf5/docs/upgrade-to-v4.md)

The new way of doing it is as follows:

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    ...
});

// Class Method
Model.myCustomQuery = function (param, param2) {  };

// Instance Method
Model.prototype.myCustomSetter = function (param, param2) {  }
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted since it's the new way of adding both class methods and instance methods.

Comment: What could be the reasons that `myCustomSetter` is undefined when accessed from outside the Model? I am having this problem. Any hint?

Comment: It's an instance method, not a class method and therefore you have to have an instance of Model in order to access it @RameshPareek

Comment: thanks@Yehonatan. What could be the reasons that even after  initializing with new keyword, I can't access these methods?

Comment: Link is dead @jlh

Comment: My problem with this solution is that vs code intellisense doesn't seem to recognize the added functions

Answer (score 12):

Use `instanceMethods` as [Jan Meier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/800016/jan-aagaard-meier) pointed out.

In your client sample:

```
// models/Client.js
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Client', {
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    instanceMethods: {
      getFullName: function() {
        return this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html#config-options

Removed `classMethods` and `instanceMethods` options from `sequelize.define`. Sequelize models are now ES6 classes. You can set class / instance level methods like this

Old

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    ...
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (model) {...}
    },
    instanceMethods: {
        someMethod: function () { ...}
    }
});
```

New

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    ...
});

// Class Method
Model.associate = function (models) {
    ...associate the models
};

// Instance Method
Model.prototype.someMethod = function () {..}
```

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem, for me it worked to add the method in the `classMethods` object

```
// models/Client.js
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Client', {
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      getFullName: function() {
        return this.first_name + ' ' + this.last_name;
      }
    }
  });
};
```